# Efficiency of resonant inductive coupling as a function of distance

Tags: energy, electricity, induction, resonance

What is the relationship between the efficiency of energy transfer between resonant inductive coupling between two coils, and the distance between the coils?

Comment: "Wireless Power Transfer via Strongly Coupled Magnetic Resonances" by 
André Kurs, Aristeidis Karalis, Robert Moffatt, J. D. Joannopoulos, Peter Fisher, Marin Soljačić Science  06 Jul 2007: Vol. 317, Issue 5834, pp. 83-86. See also http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/appnotes/00678b.pdf.

Comment: @CuriousOne Thanks, but I'm not seeing anything relating to distance between the coils in the sections on resonant circuits. I see relations to coil diameter and winding thickness, but nothing related to distance between the coils. What am I missing?

Comment: The efficiency would not depend much on distance. In high Q circuits the loading (of the receiver coil) reduces the Q of the entire transfer function. When the coils are close, the Q is low and so is the field strength. In the extreme case of a perfect transformer with no stray flux the Q would be 0. When they are far, the Q is high (up to a max. Q) and the field will build up, even though the driving power will stay the same for the same loading. At some point the Q is limited by the coil resistances, limitting the distance at which the design power can be transmitted at near 100% efficiency.

Comment: I'm asking this question out of curiosity for wireless energy transfer, where obviously distance is a key variable. It sounds like you hinted at that in your last sentence there.

Comment: The distance, or more precisely, the magnetic coupling, is only a key variable if you wanted to transmit the max. power that the coils are capable of. You have to keep in mind that a typical 5W Qi charging coil could transmit hundreds of Watt if it had a correctly designed magnetic core. So what we are trading is not efficiency but total power for distance.

Comment: That's pretty interesting, so theoretically you could achieve near max efficiency at a distance of say a mile if you only wanted to transmit a tiny amount of power?

Comment: As long as you are in the near field of the transmitter coil and as long as you can achieve high enough Q, yes, but in practice more than probably ten times coil diameter is not particularly useful because you just can't get the Q of a copper coil above much more than (a couple?) 100 or so. With superconducting coils that can achieve Q's in the tens of thousands one could, probably, do a lot better... but what for?

Comment: Well, I'd assume the coils of the receiving and sending end would need to be the same diameter, tell me if i'm wrong. But if that's the case, to really have convenient wireless power inside a house or something, you'd need more than 10 times the coil diameter to power small things like a phone for example.

Comment: The coils don't have to be equal size. A larger transmitter coil will give you more field volume and less hassle to place the device just in a good position. Other than that there won't be much advantage to it. Larger coils do give higher Q up to a point. In the days of magnetic radio antennas people did a lot of empirical research on how to optimize coils for max. Q. If you follow great-grandpa's high-skill engineering, you end up with this kind of stuff: http://www.nonstopsystems.com/radio/frank_radio_antenna_coils.htm. This will, for sure cover your entire home and scare your cat. :-)